# Chroot to gui is not working

Tags: linux, chroot

I recently bought an ssd but kept my hdd (with arch installed on both drives). What I am trying to do is run steam from my hdd using chroot.

My steps:

- Start a X server with `Xnest -ac :10.0`
- Mount the `/` partition to `/mnt` with `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/`
- Set the display variable to the X server with `DISPLAY=:10.0`
- Run X with `startx`

Here I get

```
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/robert/.Xauthority

_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
```

I've made `.Xauthority` read/write for all.

I have my home partition separate from my root partition on the drive I am chrooting into. Could this cause issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured this out.

Instead of making a separate X display, you can just run the applications on your desktop X:

```
xhost +local:
sudo chroot /mnt
export DISPLAY=:0
gedit
```